# Trigonometric integrals involving $\cos(\log x)$ and $\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

Let $k,m$ be positive integers and let $b \neq 0$ be a real number. It seems the following integral does not have a simple expression in terms of the elementary functions.
$$
I = \int_1^{e^k} \cos(2\pi m \log x) \dfrac{\sin(b x)}{x}dx.
$$
However can we get a good estimate for $|I|$ (perhaps in terms of $k,m,b$)?

Comment: the solution containes the Gamma function

Comment: Could you please explain more?